# chemfig: enhancing code

Tags: graphics, chemfig, chemistry

I am reproducing the structure of the glass silicate lattice, where an oxygen atom bridges two silicon atoms

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{chemfig}



\begin{document}

    \schemestart
    \chemfig{(Si(-[1]@{O1}O-[7]Si<:[5]O) (-[3]O)(<[5]O)(<:[7]O))}
    \schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

In particular, I had to write the oxygen atom twice with the dotted bonds. Is there a more elegant way of writing the same thing?

**EDIT**: Just the comment of the user, he asks this image taken from
https://favpng.com/png_view/sodium-silicate-silicon-oxygen-tetrahedron-chemistry-lewis-structure-quartz-png/JGt4RSXb

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the chemical structure? :-) I'm not very expert in chemistry.

Comment: Silicate ion lattice, where an O atomo is shared between two Si atomi

Comment: Something like this picture? https://img.favpng.com/21/15/9/silicon-oxygen-tetrahedron-chemistry-lewis-structure-quartz-png-favpng-eWNYPPz6AffptfWumEK96h4Y2.jpg

Comment: Yes, just like this!

Answer (score 3):

You can draw it as a cycle:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{[-1]Si*4(<:O>:Si-O-) (-[3]O) (<[5]O)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have upvoted before :-)

Comment: another approach `\chemfig{Si(-[3]O)(<[5]O)(>:[7]O<:[1]Si?)(-[1]O?)}`

Comment: @polyn Nice trick for using `?` to connect the upper-right `O` and the right `Si`! (Note in the third branch, the direction of bonds should be reversed to be `(<:[7]O>:[1]Si?)`)

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z thanks. Directions changes easy.